# Multi-Join Query, Pivot? Troubles

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps with this. I know i've seen this done before without too much pain but cant seem to find the solution

My database looks something like:

```
`tbl_user:
----------
id         ( pkey )
email
fName
lName

tbl_userSparseType:
-------------------
id         ( pkey )
varName
displayName

tbl_userSparse:
---------------
id         ( pkey )
value      ( Value of Sparse Type )
user_id    ( => tbl_user.id )
userSparseType_id     ( => tbl_userSparseType.id )
```

with sample data:

```
tbl_user:
(id,   email,              fName,   lName)
 1     Bob@example.com     Billy    Bob
 2     Betty@example.com   Betty    Sue
 3     Beam@example.com    Jim      Beam

tbl_userSparseType:
(id,   varName,    displayName)
 1     fullName    Full Name
 2     dayPhone    Day Phone
 3     nightPhone  Night Phone
 4     cellPhone   Cell Phone
 5     homeAddr    Home Address

tbl_userSparse:
(id,    value,             user_id,    userSparseType_id)
 1      Billy John Bob     1           1
 2      James B. Beam      3           1
 3      123-234-3456       1           2
 4      234-345-4567       1           4
 5      24 Best st.        2           5
 6      456-567-6789       3           3
```

I tried doing two left joins, but this gave me a tbl_user row for each sparse entry like:

```
(id, email,            fName,  lName, displayName, value)
 1,"Bob@example.com","Billy","Bob","Full Name","Billy John Bob"
 1,"Bob@example.com","Billy","Bob","Day Phone","123-234-3456"
 1,"Bob@example.com","Billy","Bob","Cell Phone","234-345-4567"
```

And despite a few 45 or so minute sessions of looking, I cant find a way to get something more like the following without explicitly naming the columns, I need a dynamic way to only pull all display names that apply to the subset of tbl_user rows being queried:

```
WHERE tbl_user.id IN (1,2)

 id | email             | fName | lName | Full Name,     | Day Phone    | Cell Phone   | 
Home Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | Bob@example.com   | Billy | Bob   | Billy John Bob | 123-234-3456 | 234-345-4567 |
 2  | Betty@example.com | Betty | Sue   |                |              |              | 24 Best St.
```

Thanks again in advance, I'm hoping this can be done without too much fuss. :\

Comment: You probably have to build the functionality into your application. What you want to do kind of violates how SQL is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function which is basically what you are trying to do. So you will need to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.  If you know the number of columns, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select u.id, 
  u.email,
  u.fname,
  u.lname,
  max(case when t.displayname = 'Full Name' then us.value end) FullName,
  max(case when t.displayname = 'Day Phone' then us.value end) DayPhone,
  max(case when t.displayname = 'Cell Phone' then us.value end) CellPhone,
  max(case when t.displayname = 'Home Address' then us.value end) HOmeAddress
from tbl_user u
left join tbl_userSparse us
  on u.id = us.user_id
left join tbl_userSparseType t
  on us.userSparseType_id = t.id
where u.id in (1, 2) 
group by u.id, u.email, u.fname,u.lname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68425/9)

Now if you want to perform this dynamically, meaning you do not know ahead of time the columns to transpose, then you should review the following article:

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Your code would look like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when t.displayname = ''',
      t.displayname,
      ''' then us.value end) AS ',
      replace(t.displayname, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_userSparse us
left join tbl_userSparseType t
  on us.userSparseType_id = t.id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.id, u.email, u.fname, u.lname, ', @sql, ' 
                  from tbl_user u
                  left join tbl_userSparse us
                    on u.id = us.user_id
                  left join tbl_userSparseType t
                    on us.userSparseType_id = t.id
                  where u.id in (1, 2) 
                  group by u.id, u.email, u.fname, u.lname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68425/10)